# Understand Javascript syntax used in the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've found this JavaScript code that allows to upload files asynchronously but the are some parts that I don't understand. any pointers or explanation highly appreciated - thanks in advance,

```
// Ajax File upload with jQuery and XHR2
// Sean Clark http://square-bracket.com
// xhr2 file upload
// data is optional
$.fn.upload = function(remote, data, successFn, progressFn) {
    // if we dont have post data, move it along
    if (typeof data != "object") {
        progressFn = successFn;
        successFn = data;
    }
    //What is doing here?
    return this.each(function() {
        if ($(this)[0].files[0]) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
```

Comment: Mind telling us which parts? Or that whole snippet of code?

Comment: I've added a better explained comment

Comment: Honestly, all I see is overkill... It simply loops what's returned by a jQuery selector (`<input type="file">` probably) and fetches the file to upload. `FormData` is a way to send form asynchronously.

Comment: Not to be mean, but `$(this)[0]` is a pretty good indicator that the author of this code doesn't really have a very deep understanding of things. It's effectively identical to just referencing `this`, but is wasteful with memory and CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // What's it doing here?
> ```

The value of `this` is a reference to the object on which `upload` was invoked. Seems like you're talking about a jQuery object here.

So `this.each(...` is invoked, passing it a callback function. Because there's a `return` statement before that call, the value that `.each()` returns is returned from the `upload` function, which I believe will be the same `this` value in this case.

Here's a simplified demo:

```js
// constructor function
function Test() {
  this.counter = 0;
}

// instance methods

Test.prototype.upload = function() {
  // `this` refers to the object in which `upload` was called, so it
  // has access to the `foo` method, which it invokes.
  return this.foo(function() {
    return "foo was called";
  });
};

Test.prototype.foo = function(callback) {
  // The `foo` method expects a callback function, which it invokes and
  // logs whatever the callback returned. It then returns the `this`
  // object to the caller.
  console.log(callback());
  return this;
};

var t = new Test();

var res = t.upload();

console.log(t === res);
```